# Is there syntax just like #region #endregion in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know I can use #region #endregion to surround a code snippets in C#, is there a similar syntax in Kotlin? Thanks!

```
   #region MyRegion
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    } 
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

**In IntelliJ IDEA (or Android Studio)**: yes, [you can](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-source-code.html#code_folding). You can do it by using `//region` and `//endregion` comments or by using `//<editor-fold desc="...">` and `//</editor-fold>`.

Example:

```
//region name

fun someCode() { ... }
fun someMoreCode() { ... }

//endregion

// or

//<editor-fold desc="name">

fun someCode() { ... }
fun someMoreCode() { ... }

//</editor-fold>
```

Comment: Thanks!


But //region... //endregion don't work well in Android Studio!

I collapse a code snippets with //region... //endregion in Android Studio, then I move the project to anthor folder, then I open the code again , I find the code snippets surrounded with //region... //endregion  don't be collapsed!

I do the same thing in C#,  the collapsed code snippets will keep collapse even if I move the project to another folder!

Comment: @HelloCW I think that's because how IntelliJ stores data about snippets in a different place than Visual Studio does and that's why. I don't think you can do much about it

Comment: What is the difference between using "region" and "<editor-fold" ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper The only difference is the syntax. There's no other real difference

Comment: @Mibac OK thanks. I suggest writing this in the answer.

Comment: I noticed it is not working well unless I leave an empty line after `// region`

Answer (score 12):

There are more supported styles (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-folding.html#supported_comments)

The Netbeans Style

```
//<editor-fold desc="YOUR REGION NAME">
fun main(vararg args: String) { ... }
...
//</editor-fold>
```

or the visual studio style

```
//region YOUR REGION NAME
fun main(vararg args: String) { ... }
...
//endregion
```

They can be collapsed and expanded in IntelliJ. When it's collapsed, only the description is displayed.

Comment: #region ... #endregion is more natural with usual Kotlin comments.