# Android Studio using Kotlin - is there a way to automatically fold multiline comments?

Tags: android-studio

Been getting into Android Studio (and Android development in general) lately, mostly a personal challenge to make a modern version of an app my mum loves but hasn't been updated in ages. But my life story isn't the point, and that's not just because it's not that interesting.

**The actual question:**
Is there a way to make Android Studio do automatic folding for block comments (i.e. `/*` to `*/`) in Kotlin files? In *Settings > Editor > Code Folding* there's options for documentation (in general) and multiline comments for C or Java, but no settings specific to Kotlin, and just one for Android in general (which has nothing to do with comments).

**The reasoning:** Because I'm still pretty new at this, there's a lot of things I've tried but haven't worked, and comment out instead of deleting because I still might be able to learn something from them later. There's also some big  blocks of logging code for debugging that are great when I'm trying to debug but in the way (given I usually write them in the middle of classes or methods) when I'm not, so I comment them out. It's just annoying having to fold several sections of comments whenever I open a file.

**The "well duh" solution?:** I could set them as documentation comments, which would hopefully get automatically folded, but if I start writing documentation (like I really should get around to) they'll get mixed in and that would be annoying.

**What I've tried so far:** Going through all the settings with a fine tooth comb (and I'll freely admit I could have gone over something obvious) and searched for plugins for code folding, about the only one I could find is https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12007-foldingplus which doesn't seem to do anything about this particular problem.

Can anyone help me out here, other than maybe "be less of a newbie in general"?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/44915676/812013 ?

Answer (score 0):

With Android Studio Arctic Fox I found that if you highlight a region that has the comments in question, you can right-click on it and one of the options will be `Folding`. From the expanded options select `Fold Selection / Remove Region` and the selected comments will fold.

[image: screenshot]